# Is there any way to shoot a full sphere panorama (horizontal + vertical)?

Tags: camera, photos

I've tried a few apps for shooting panoramas on my Android device (Galaxy S4), but I cannot find one that is able to shoot both horizontally and vertically.

I would like to be able to capture a whole room, to eventually be used as a custom Google Maps Street View panorama on a website.  Is there any way to accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with your native camera app. But **you have to have JB 4.2 *(Not 4.1.x)*.**

1. Go to the camera. Tap on the camera icon and pick the item that looks like a small globe with a panorama stretched over it. That's the Photo Sphere mode.
2. Take a picture as usual.
3. Keep your camera steady.
4. You should see a message to align your camera with the blue dot. Tilt your camera up, down, left, or right slowly to match the center of the screen with the blue dot for the next area. The picture will snap automatically when you get there.
   Keep going for as long as you wish to take as many images as possible and make your complete Photo Sphere.

*Note: this may look a little weird if you try to take pictures of people, since they tend to move between shots. Landscapes and interior shots are your best bets.*

Comment: Google calls this a "Photosphere" if I recall.

Comment: Samsung didn't include the stock Android camera software with my S4, but I was able to install it easily.  No root required.  The APK filename was SGS4_Photosphere_Gallery.apk, and I found it at http://d-h.st/tK6.

Comment: Something worth stressing: keep your phone in the same spot, and rotate it. Don't rotate yourself, or otherwise move the phone from its starting position in space, or that'll mess it up. It's easier if you have something like a tripod you can use to ensure it stays in the same place.